# Read object from package - java

Tags: java, object

How can I read object from package?
I put my object to myObject.data file..

- Object name is = `myObject.data`
- Name of package is = `examplePackage`

  ```
  MyObject value = null;
  try {
      try (ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
              "PACKAGE ....... ? myData.data""
      ))) {
          value = (MyObject) is.readObject();
      }
  } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("Error: " + e);
  }
  return value;
  ```

I tried `getClass().getResource()` but does not work

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "read object from package"? ObjectInputStream is for reading a serialized object from file.

Comment: You should be using Class.forName to get the Class and then inititate the object from it.

Comment: what object? I think you are trying to read .data file (not object). but please elaborate

Comment: `but does not work` what exactly doesn't works? what error / exception you get?

Comment: Sorry, i want read file(contains my MyObject) from package.

Comment: @Frakcool java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: for package you intend your JAR file? where is the file inside the JAR?

Comment: @user3784463 please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the whole Stack Trace, so you can get better help

Comment: this does not work? path = "/examplePackage/myObject.data"; getClass().getResource(path); this assumes that your code is declared in the examplePackage package

Comment: @mxb Thank you, i tried  getClass().getResource(path).getPath() and it work BUT only in my IDE, in console on the desktop does not work. I get an error: FileNotFoundException.

Comment: print out the path and post it here

Comment: you can also shorten the code using this InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/examplePackage/myObject.data");

Comment: @mxb in IDE(netbeans) - /C:/_PROSTREDI_PROJEKTY/Netbeans/PRJ5_Parser/build/classes/data/hm_pj.data, in CMD(win 8) - file:/C:/Users/MyPc/Desktop/PRJ5_Parser.jar!/data/hm_pj.data

Comment: please check if data/hm_pj.data is present in the source folder of your NetBeans project. Also, check that your JAR contains this file, opening it with WinZip or similar

Comment: @mxb BUT, if i now tried your code InputStream inputStreaminputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data/hm_pj.data"); it work :-)

Comment: ok, I'll post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code as follows:

```
MyObject value = null;
try {
    try (ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(
      getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("data/hm_pj.data"); 
    ))) {
        value = (MyObject) is.readObject();
    }
} catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + e);
}
return value;
```